# Objective C - How to Stringify an id

Tags: objective-c, string

I need to compare a key object from a div to a string. I access the key object in a `for` loop:

```
for (id key in _photosDic) {
    ...
}
```

In the loop, I want to compare the key with a string. Do I have to convert the key to a string?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is this `div` you are referencing?

Comment: @Richard, re your comments on pgb's answer: If you send `description` to the same object twice in the course of one program, you are guaranteed to get the same result. Comparing those two should not be a problem. The issue arises with expecting the return to have a specific format or value, because that could (potentially) change and not be documented between framework versions. That said, it's still not the answer to this question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell it is NOT guaranteed to give the same result. I myself have written a NSString subclass that includes the address of the string in the `-description`, for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Richard, again: the _same object_ twice.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, no what I was saying is that my object returned that subclass, and `-isEqualToString:` would return false.

Comment: @JoshCaswell compiler error, 'too many errors', aborting.

Comment: see my comment to the aweser above please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` type can be anything so the first step would be to check if it is actually a `NSString` or not.

for that you can use this:

```
if ([idObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) 
{
    //Now do a simple casting
    NSString *myString = (NSString *)idObject;

    //Now compare the strings
    NSComparisonResult result = [myOtherString compare:myString];
}
```

Comment: in deed it is the right aweser, and I will mark it has that. But I'm making a mistake. I'm passing and array of photos from a thumbnails view, to a fullscreen view. So I'm passing the selected photo and the array. So when the FullscreenView is loaded I can load all the photos, and change the offset of the view, to the selected view. The problem is that I'm sending the photo.description, because I can only store strings on the dictionary, or am I wrong? [photosViewDic setObject:[photosDic objectForKey:@"URI"] forKey:photo];     When i put that i get error. photo.description works fine.