# How to use [self pushControllerWithName:xxx context:NSdictionary]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

Working with WatchOS:

In InterfaceContoller.m 's `(void)session .... didReceiveMessage ...`

```
NSDictionary *request = @{@"testkey":@"testvalue"};
//i've also tried context:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
[self pushControllerWithName:@"Controller" context:request];
```

In Controller.m's `-(void)awakeWithContext:(id)context`

```
[super awakeWithContext:context];

NSLog(@"context = %@", context);
```

I got `context = <InterfaceController: 0x14d80a30>` instead of the NSObject I set.

What I wanted to do is, pass a value during the pushController method, and Controller.m will check for the value and perform different action base on the value.
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was a mistake on my end.

I got that reply because I've put the `context:self`, and i was using that code instead of the NSDictionary stated in the question.

Alternatively, since the `context` is an ID, we can check the ID for the class we want (NSDictionary, NSString, NSNumber etc) by doing so:

```
if ([context isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
//[NSDictionary class] to check for NSDictionary. Use NSString, NSNumber for the one you need etc
{
    NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary*)context;
    NSLog(@"context dict = %@", dict);
}
```

Silly me!

Reference: [Objective C - How to Stringify an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298840/objective-c-how-to-stringify-an-id)